# Merge two action for form using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have inline validation and its working well, but when I click its not submitting so I have added if the all the fields are validated it says, your are not a human, Please click again, I dont want this step its confusing for user, How can I fix this code, when user clicks submit button it should validate all the field and submit.

```js
$(function validateForm() {
  $("#cname").validate({
    expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
    message: "Please enter the Name"
  });
  $("#cnumber").validate({
    expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[0-9\.\-\/]+$/)) return true; else return false;",
    message: "Please enter a valid Phone number"
  });
  $("#csubject").validate({
    expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
    message: "Please enter the Subject"
  });
  $("#cemail").validate({
    expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[^\\W][a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-\\.]+([a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-\\.]+)*\\@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/)) return true; else return false;",
    message: "Please enter a valid Email ID"
  });
  $("#cmessage").validate({
    expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
    message: "Please enter the Message"
  });

  // Get the form.
  var form = $('#ajax-contact');

  // Get the messages div.
  var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

  $(form).validated(function(e) {
    // alert("Use this call to make AJAX submissions.");
    $(formMessages).addClass('wait').text("You are a human! Click the submit button again to confirm your request.");

    $(form).submit(function(e) {

      // Serialize the form data.
      $(formMessages).addClass('wait').text("please wait...");

      e.preventDefault();

      var formData = $(form).serialize();
      var action = $(this).attr('action');



      $.post(action, $(form).serialize(),
          function(data) {
            if (data.match('success') != null) $('#ajax-contact .form-group, #ajax-contact .theme-btn').slideUp('slow');
          }
        )
        .done(function(response) {
          // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
          $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
          $(formMessages).addClass('success');


          // Set the message text.
          $(formMessages).text(response);



          // Clear the form.
          $('#cname').val('');
          $('#cemail').val('');
          $('#cnumber').val('');
          $('#csubject').val('');
          $('#cmessage').val('');

          gtag('event', 'form_submission', {
            'event_category': 'contact_us',
            'event_label': 'success'
          });

        })
        .fail(function(data) {
          // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
          $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
          $(formMessages).addClass('error');

          // Set the message text.
          if (data.responseText !== '') {
            $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
          } else {
            $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
          }
        })

    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="mailer/function/smtpemail.php" class="wpcf7-form AdvancedForm" autocomplete="on">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="cname" type="text" name="cname" value="" placeholder="NAME">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="cemail" type="email" data-missing="This field is required" data-mismatch="Please include a valid email" name="cemail" value="" placeholder="EMAIL">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="cnumber" type="text" maxlength="15" name="cnumber" value="" placeholder="MOBILE">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="csubject" type="text" name="csubject" value="" placeholder="SUBJECT">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea id="cmessage" draggable="false" name="cmessage" placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button onclick='return validateForm()' type="submit" id="submit" class="theme-btn btn-style-four">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div id="form-messages"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why don't you simply remove the line? `$(formMessages).addClass('wait').text("You are a human! Click the submit button again to confirm your request.");`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava please check the loop. Even though I removed this line I have to press the submit button twice. Thats the problem.

Comment: what library are you using?

Comment: You should be calling function validateForm(){} in your script.
 $(function validateForm(){ Your code }); //wrong
function validateForm() {Your code} //Correct approch

Also - No need of  $(form).validated(function(e){ } , Once the form validation is completed, $(form).submit(function (e) { } will be triggered , move " $(formMessages).addClass('wait').text("You are a human! Click the submit button again to confirm your request.");" inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```js
function validateForm() {
 $("#cname").validate({
  expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
  message: "Please enter the Name"
 });
 $("#cnumber").validate({
  expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[0-9\.\-\/]+$/)) return true; else return false;",
  message: "Please enter a valid Phone number"
 });
 $("#csubject").validate({
  expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
  message: "Please enter the Subject"
 });
 $("#cemail").validate({
  expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[^\\W][a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-\\.]+([a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-\\.]+)*\\@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/)) return true; else return false;",
  message: "Please enter a valid Email ID"
 });
 $("#cmessage").validate({
  expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
  message: "Please enter the Message"
 });

 // Get the form.
 var form = $('#ajax-contact');

 // Get the messages div.
 var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

 //$(form).validated(function(e){

  // alert("Use this call to make AJAX submissions.");
  //$(formMessages).addClass('wait').text("You are a human! Click the submit button again to confirm your request.");

  $(form).submit(function (e) {
   $(formMessages).addClass('wait').text("You are a human! Click the submit button again to confirm your request.");
   // Serialize the form data.
   $(formMessages).addClass('wait').text("please wait...");

   e.preventDefault();

   var formData = $(form).serialize();
   var action = $(this).attr('action');



   $.post(action, $(form).serialize(),
    function (data) {
     if (data.match('success') != null) $('#ajax-contact .form-group, #ajax-contact .theme-btn').slideUp('slow');
    }
   )
    .done(function (response) {
     // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
     $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
     $(formMessages).addClass('success');


     // Set the message text.
     $(formMessages).text(response);



     // Clear the form.
     $('#cname').val('');
     $('#cemail').val('');
     $('#cnumber').val('');
     $('#csubject').val('');
     $('#cmessage').val('');

     gtag('event', 'form_submission', {
      'event_category': 'contact_us',
      'event_label': 'success'
     });

    })
    .fail(function (data) {
     // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
     $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
     $(formMessages).addClass('error');

     // Set the message text.
     if (data.responseText !== '') {
      $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
     } else {
      $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
     }
    })

  });


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<form  id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="mailer/function/smtpemail.php"  class="wpcf7-form AdvancedForm" autocomplete="on">
 <div class="form-group">
  <input  id="cname" type="text" name="cname" value="" placeholder="NAME">
  </div>
  
  
 <div class="form-group">
  <input id="cemail" type="email" data-missing="This field is required" data-mismatch="Please include a valid email"  name="cemail" value=""
   placeholder="EMAIL">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <input id="cnumber" type="text" maxlength="15" name="cnumber" value="" placeholder="MOBILE">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <input id="csubject" type="text" name="csubject" value="" placeholder="SUBJECT">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <textarea id="cmessage" draggable="false" name="cmessage" placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE"></textarea>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <button onclick='return validateForm()' type="submit" id="submit" class="theme-btn btn-style-four">Submit</button>
 </div>
 <div id="form-messages"></div>
</form>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: working, but if few fields are not entered its automatically clearing the form.

Comment: @Guna , Please check whether your field validations are working well. Please mark it as answer as it is working.